# Pulling information from OpenWeatherMap API when state (country) changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Currently, I am only able to pull information when the name of the country is already loaded, I add the code, save it, then it's updated on localhost. But when I type in another country I get the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')`. For example, my code `{weather.main.temp}` works but only when the state = "france" is already set before.

My sub component:

```
const WeatherInfo = ({ country }) => {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${country.capital}&appid=${api_key}&units=imperial`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setWeather(response.data)
            })
    }, [country])
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Weather in {country.capital}</h3>
            <p><b>Temperature</b>{weather.main.temp}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is initialized as an empty object when `WeatherInfo` is created. Therefore `weather.main` is undefined and you get the error when you try to get the attribute `temp` from undefined.

You can resolve this by having some conditional chaining or some ternary operators depending on what you want displayed when `weather` is an empty object.

```
return (
    <div>
        <h3>Weather in {country.capital}</h3>
        <p><b>Temperature</b>{weather.main?.temp}</p>
    </div>
)
```